# Does the Cosumi Go site sometimes get the score wrong?

Tags: go, scoring

Cosumi claims that I won this game by 37 points:

[image: Go board with even territory between the two sides]

— [[9×9, Level 0] Black(You) Wins by 37 Points - Go Browser Game COSUMI](https://www.cosumi.net/en/replay/?b=You&w=COSUMI&k=0&r=b37&bs=9&l=0&gr=dfgdedcfcecggehdhefcfdgbdcdgbfbgafdecdeffgagbdffgfehfhebdbfigieihhdacaeabbieifidhgfeecegeedfddbitttt&ds=daeaebgbfcgdhdidie&bm=gdgieb)

But it looks even to me.

Am I missing something, or does the site sometimes get the score completely wrong?

EDIT:

Strange.  The next morning, the same URL shows the upper-right corner as captured:

[image]

That might account for the score but, as far as I can tell, White still owns that territory.

Something strange is going on here.  (Does Cosumi have a bug-reporting mechanism?)

Comment: The score is wrong, both white groups are alive

Answer (score 3):

You are right that the top right belongs to White with correct play, but according to the programme [Sabaki](https://github.com/SabakiHQ/Sabaki) White wins by one point (because they have a captive). It is conceivable, but somewhat unlikely, that White could make enough errors for Black to win.

#### The score

Sabaki calculates the score like this for [area scoring](https://senseis.xmp.net/?AreaScoring):

[image]

and like this with [territory scoring](https://senseis.xmp.net/?TerritoryScoring):

[image]

#### The top right

To be on the safe side, I plugged your SGF into [KataGo](https://github.com/lightvector/KataGo/) (via Sabaki), and it showed me a ko in the top right that Black cannot win: not only do they have hardly any threats, even if they did, they could not finish the ko in their favour.

The sequence that KataGo found was this:

```
$$Bcm1 Trying for a ko
$$ +---------+
$$ |..XOO.a25|
$$ |.X.XO.O1c|
$$ |..,XXO4d3|
$$ |.XXXXXOOO|
$$ |..XOXOXXO|
$$ |XXOOOOX.X|
$$ |OOOOOX.X.|
$$ |....OX.X.|
$$ |.O..OOX..|
$$ +---------+
```

Unfortunately for Black, White simply has to connect with ➅ at **a** and Black has no way of finishing the ko to kill White. White can just wait for Black to run out of threats and then capture at **c** and **d**.

Black’s only chance is if White plays the ko wrongly, for example:

```
$$Wcm6 White messes up (9 retakes, 13 @ 7)
$$ +---------+
$$ |..XOO36OX|
$$ |.X.XO2OX1|
$$ |0.,XXOO.X|
$$ |9XXXXXOOO|
$$ |57XOXOXXO|
$$ |XXOOOOX.X|
$$ |OOOOOXxX.|
$$ |....OX.X.|
$$ |.O..OOX..|
$$ +---------+
```

- capturing ➅ instead of connecting at ⓫,
- threatening with ➉ instead of the deadlier threat at **x**,
- missing **x** again after Black takes at ⓫ and therefore giving up the ko, so
- Black wins by 27 (area) or 26 (territory).